# ember functions - unexpected token

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

Am using ember version 2.5.1
I get the below syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: frontend/controllers/hmi/config/buckets-edit.js: Unexpected token (36:8)
  isFancy: false,
  firstName: {
    if (this.get('isFancy')) {
      return 'Hannah';
    } else {
      return 'nameless';
```

My code:

test.hbs;

```
      Hello my name is {{firstName}}
      <p>
          Check box if your name is Hannah: {{input type="checkbox" checked=isFancy}}
      </p>
```

controller/test.js;

```
  firstName: {
    if (this.get('isFancy')) {
      return 'Hannah';
    } else {
      return 'nameless';
    }.property('isFancy'),

  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computed property should look like this.

```
firstName: function(){
 if (this.get('isFancy')) {
   return 'Hannah';
} else {
  return 'nameless';
}.property('isFancy')
```